# Access string in JSON object

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, wcf

I am using javascript to access the below WCF Ajax Web Service.

```
[OperationContract]
    public string Test()
    {
        return "test";
    }
```

I am using the below javascript to execute the method and have a button hooked up to the function.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
<Services>
    <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/AjaxService.svc" />
</Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>

<script type="text/javascript">
function TestFunction() {
    alert(JSON.stringify(AjaxService.Test()));
}
</script>
```

Now when I run the code the alert says undefined. However when I check in firebug I can see that the Webmethod has actually worked correctly. I get an http response of {"d":"test"}.

How can I access the string that I have returned from the Ajax Web Method in javascript?

Comment: Could you try console.log(AjaxService.Text()) to see what is the output?

Answer (score 0):

First, try using jQuery for JSON decoding for multiple browsers support, using for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

Then you can decode the JSON string using:

```
var response = $.parseJSON(AjaxService.Test());
alert(response['d']); // This should show 'test'
```

Comment: He didn't mention jQuery anywhere in his question, or use the tag.  And its not needed for what you're doing.

Comment: So how do you know that's not working because of the JSON.stringify() which is not cross-browser? He wants that working.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure exactly whats wrong with his code, he hasn't given us enough information.  If he's being passed a JSON string then he should be running JSON.parse() instead of stringify and doesn't need jQuery.  Regardless I think we need a bit more info, or somebody who knows more about WCF than I do.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Maybe he can test those two lines and if that's not working he could tell us for more possible solutions.

Comment: No it doesn't work using Jquery either. What else can I give to assist? I am stuck with this. As you can see there isn't much more source code as it is just a prototype so I can learn how asp.net and javascript work together,  which at this point isn't great but can't be worse  than Microsoft ajax!